# Set paragraph text to JSON data result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I'm struggling to find an example where one uses some JSON data result and set a paragraphs' text to it.

This is my JSON result...

```
[{"availability":58.2,"oee":44.5,"performance":41.2,"quality":68.9}]
```

All I want to do is set the paragraphs' text equal to the "oee" result.

This is what I've tried so var, but it's not working. Don't know why cause there are no JavaScript errors showing up in the Java Debugger that I'm using.

```
<script type="">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://....../mesmobileservice/MESService.svc/JSON/data/macid=1", function (data) {
        $("#mac001OEE").text($(this).data("oee")); 
    });              
});
```

This is for a simple Kendo UI app.

Thanks :)

Comment: OK, this looks like jQuery - in which case you should mention that (and not everyone knows that "Kendo UI" means jQuery).  Why the heck are you calling `$()` on `this`, and why are you looking for `data` as a property of the result, when it's passed in as an argument to your function?  And even if that were the right `data`, why are you calling it as if it were a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#mac001OEE").text(data[0].oee);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#mac001OEE").text(data[0].oee);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get a JSON string via AJAX, jQuery translates it to a Object. It would be more elegant in my humble opinion if you would give a label to your object:

```
{"myObj": {
    "availability":58.2,
    "oee":44.5,"performance":41.2,
    "quality":68.9
   }
}
```

Then you could access your data like this:

```
data.myObj.oee
```